# How to get if statement in php to work if there´re more conditions inside if

Tags: php

I have 2 variable sent from ajax to php user and email

```
if ($key=="user"){
    //and sql will check if user name is exist or not

    if($stmt->rowCount() >0); //if user is exist
   echo"user is already exist";

    if(!preg_match('/^[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%][0-9A-Za-z!@#$% ]+[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]$/',$user));

    echo"bad user name";

}
```

How to get it work ? I might have more `if` statement inside the big `if` (maybe)

Comment: I think you should read some about PHP first. You can start from here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php

Comment: if (x) { if (y) { ....; } if (z) { ....; }}

Comment: I have more explaination:
This will send echo to ajax, and in the form in use "onkeyup" to activate javascript....which mean if i type some words not finish yet the error "bad user" comming.

That´s why...

Comment: I got it now:
The reason it throw the echo"bad user" is because inside the preg_match there´re a syntex to minimum 2 strings must be type in..so that´s why ! I will be careful of this..but thanks.

ps. Sometimes my question seems stupid but before I asked I have tried and do the reseach...
Sometimes people can be error and forget small fault..

Thank for answer !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use curly braces and add more conditions like so:

```
if ($key=="user")
{
    //and sql will check if user name is exist or not
    if($stmt->rowCount() >0)
    { 
    //if user is exist
    echo"user is already exist";

        if(!preg_match('/^[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%][0-9A-Za-z!@#$% ]+[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]$/',$user)) 
        {
        echo"bad user name";
        }

        if(condition2)
        {
        //code
        }

        if(condition3)
        {
        //code
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you don't need a semicolon at the end of an if statement. Refer to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) for more information.

Comment: I have done it before, but the problem is:
This will send echo to ajax and show the error.
If I use this method, the error will show "bad user name" even I´m not finishing type the name yet.

So that´s why...And I don´t know if there´re a way.

Comment: I got it now:
The reason it throw the echo"bad user" is because inside the preg_match there´re a syntex to minimum 2 strings must be type in..so that´s why ! I will be careful of this..but thanks.

ps. Sometimes my question seems stupid but before I asked I have tried and do the reseach...
Sometimes people can be error and forget small fault..

Thank for answer !!